# Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'wockhardt_indigo.stock_levels.id' isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, eloquent

I've recently started getting an error with the below statement

```
Model::select(DB::raw('*, SUM(`unrestrict`) as sumUnrestrict, SUM(`quarantine`) as sumQuarantine'))->with(['materialDescription'])->orderBy('mat_no')->groupBy('mat_no')->get();
```

The error is

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'wockhardt_indigo.stock_levels.id' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Any idea to solve? TIA

Answer (score 1):

You must assign explictally the column you need and these must match teh column in group by  eg:

```
Model::select(DB::raw('mat_no,  
SUM(`unrestrict`) as sumUnrestrict, 
SUM(`quarantine`) as sumQuarantine'))->
with(['materialDescription'])->
orderBy('mat_no')->
groupBy('mat_no')->get();
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need all the columns, would be slightly inefficient to otherwise bring back all the columns when I only needed 1 of them :P

I have resolved the issue by disabling the strict SQL flag in Laravel. It seems to be an issue many users are facing, see https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997

Comment: @MichaelBrewster  . you shuld set the proper column in group by if you need  many columns ..

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue within the Laravel Framework. Laravel 5.3 ships with the strict mode in SQL turned on which doesn't work great with Eloquent, changing to false in config/database.php solves the solution and brings back the 5.2 behaviour.